# how to structure my mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this on my website

[image]

each time I click on a cell the background is changing and the unique id is stored in an array.

What kind of structure should i use in my database to store everyone is disponibility, one table with a field "name" (name of the user) and a different field for every hour (11*7 = 77 field + name field) ? or there is better solution.

I want to know when 5 users have the same disponibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correct you don't need to save all the hours, therefore there is no need of 77 columns.

I think it would be easier to maintain database of two tables:

Users:
`| ID | NAME |`

Disponibility:

`| ID | DAY | HOUR | USERID |`

And you should save just the marked hours